# How to round xml value after decimal in php?

Tags: php, xml, rounding

Hi I get a value like this in php: 0.3350 and I want to show only 3 numbers, like 0.335.

The code:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://ir.euroinvestor.com/ServiceEngine/api/xml/reply/RequestStockDataBundle?apiversion=1&solutionID=2614&customerKey=OpgPowerVenturesPlc&instrumentTypes=Listing';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die("feed not loading");

$Ask = $xml->Data->InstrumentEntry[0]->Ask;

echo $Ask;

?>
```

I tried to add:

```
echo round($Ask, 2);
```

But get then only 0

Comment: your code works with me, I get 47

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cast the value to float and then [round()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php), like:

```
$Ask = (float) $xml->Data->InstrumentEntry[0]->Ask;
echo round($Ask, 3);
```

Comment: @HzrCan I run your code in my bash console, with php test.php, it works well

Comment: @KrisRoofe ow that didn't work for me. I get only 0.